# How to fix parent hover issues with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am having issues with my child element still acting as `:hover` for my parent element, which I don't want to happen.

Is there a way, using **css** to stop my child element from activating the hover for my parent element? [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aftdwqen/)

Here is a basic example of my issue:

```css
div.wrapper {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:fixed;
 margin:auto auto;
 background-color:rgba(34,34,34,0.5);
 
 transition:background-color ease-in-out 0.25s;
 z-index:98;
}
div.wrapper:hover {
 background-color:rgba(34,34,34,0.25);
 cursor:pointer;
}
    div.wrapper > div.container {
        width:400px;
        height:100%;
        position:relative;
        background:#3498DB;
        box-shadow:0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, when you hover over the blue area (child) it still triggers the gray area (parent). How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: ([JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5fq024L/))

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="back">

    </div>
    <div class="container">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    margin:auto auto;

    z-index:0;
}
div.back {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:rgba(34,34,34,0.5);

    transition:background-color ease-in-out 0.25s;
    z-index: 1;
}
div.back:hover {
    background-color:rgba(34,34,34,0.25);
    cursor:pointer;
}
div.wrapper > div.container {
    width:400px;
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background:#3498DB;
    box-shadow:0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    z-index: 2;
}
```

hovering child always trigger parents hover, but you can make a fake parent to reach your goal.

Comment: Although there are a bit too many changes, this is a pretty nice trick. Good Idea!

Answer (score 1):

Why would you doing that?

If you want hover the child, just add `hover` to child.

If you want hover works for both, why not putting them as siblings not parent-child .

Hope this can help you.